# Merge nodes temporary for a query

Tags: neo4j

I tried to use the search to see if anyone else asked this question, but I wasn't able to find anything that solves my problem. Please don't blame, if I haven't see the correct question.

As I tried to describe in the title, I would like to merge nodes for a request. Think of a graph which contains family trees. My graph has multiple families in it. Every family is represented by their members. So you have a connection to your brother A-[:hasBrother]->B and so on. You also have connections to other families. E.g. You are connected to someone of another family by A-[:knows]->C. Now I would like to merge the families, because I am interested in the connection between family X to Z. But on this path, I'd like to see a family as one node, that has connections to other family nodes. Is this possible with Neo4j?

I have an example:

```
A is part of Family 1; b,c,d is part of Family 2; e is part of family 3

A<-->B

B<-->C

C<-->D

D<-->E

E<-->F
```

When I'm looking for the length of the connection between family 1 and, I'd like to get two as result.

I hope you got my question and you are able to help me.
At least, thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad. Your example is also confusing, because as best as I can tell, there is only one connection between family 1 and family 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.   First you need a way of identifying families.  I'll show a simple example, assuming that last name identifies families, and that you have this data.  Just as a note, it's probably NOT that simple, but as an example I need to use something:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
MERGE (f:Family { name: p.lastName }) // Create a family with this last name.
MERGE (p)-[:part_of]->(f);   // Link everybody to the right family.
```

Now what you want to do is simple:

```
MATCH (f1:Family)<-[:part_of]-(p1:Person)-[:knows]->(p2)-[:part_of]->(f2:Family)
WHERE f1 <> f2 and f1.id < f2.id
MERGE (f1)-[:knows]->(f2)
```

Basically this says when you have two different families (f1 and f2) where people in those families know one another, then those families know one another.  I added an ordering predicate (f1.id < f2.id) to prevent from considering the same pairs in both directions.

Note that depending on how many "knows" links you have, this could take some time to run.  Basically you have to consider every single pairwise person relationship to update the links correctly.

You don't have to materialize the fact that families know one another. Notice that in that `MATCH` clause of the second query, we already know that f1 and f2 know each other.   If you can just re-run that match as needed, you don't have to actually create a new relationship from f1 to f2.

Comment: Note that the family nodes and relationships must be deleted afterwards if you want this information to be temporary (per the question title).

Comment: Yes - actually I added that node about materializing the family "knows" relationships because for a large graph, materializing them would be costly enough I probably wouldn't do it in the first place.   It's one of those O(n^2) queries.